# Emacs: using pdbtrack (python.el)

Tags: python, debugging, emacs

I've been studying Emacs as a Python IDE. There's an excellent, up-to-date solution: emacs-for-python by Gabriele Lanar. Unfortunately, I can't employ pdbtrack. That is, dropping into pdb I am not shown Python source buffer with a cursor at the current line, etc. The only way to make it sort of work is this ugly hack: http://page.sourceforge.net/tricks.html#Running_pdb_under_emacs
Moreover, Gud probably has never been the way to go with an interpreted language like Python: (hyperlink not allowed)
There's one discussion, https://github.com/fgallina/python.el/issues/43 , but it leads nowhere.
I've also discovered python-pdbtrack-activate variable, but it's set to t by default anyway. There's one word of hope: "BTW it should be possible to add the pdbtrack filter function globally, but haven't tested and I don't think I would activate such thing by default". Why, I don't mind such thing being inactive by default, I'd just like to know how to turn it on...
The ability to drop into the debugger via pdb.set_trace() as nicely as possible is essential, IMO. I hope it's possible right now.

Comment: What is wrong with python-mode that comes with emacs and includes an interface to pdb - for improved version see https://launchpad.net/python-mode/+announcement/9699

Comment: Nothing wrong with python-mode.el _per_ _se_. It is not compatible with the otherwise excellent emacs-for-python bundle, though. So I face a choice: either get an answer for the present question, or build my own flying circus around python-mode.el. The latter would be another story and another bunch of questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your precise question, but it solves your issue as well.
I use [pdb++](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdbpp/) inside emacs' term mode: pdb++'s "sticky mode" gives me the equivalent of pdbtrack, with the advantage that it doesn't have to open a buffer for each file it visits (because it simply displays the source code in the term buffer).

As an additional bonus, I also get colorful tab completion as the pdb++ prompt :-)

If you use py.test, you might want to check also my [pytest-emacs](https://bitbucket.org/antocuni/pytest-emacs/src/5ba9a434db5d/pytest.el), which automatically starts py.test in a term buffer so that pdb works out of the box.

Comment: Ah! That's your own brew... Thank you very much, Antonio! I feel flattered. Will give pdb++ a try as soon as possible.

Comment: Won't run: "RuntimeError: terminal doesn't have the required 'clear' capability".

Comment: I see: it isn't meant to be integrated with Emacs. It's probably all right: I may be an inexperienced user, but Emacs console didn't impress me.

Comment: So much for a carefully researched question... Nonetheless, pdb++ turned out to be a very satisfactory solution. Thank you very much, Antonio! I just put `editor = '${EDITOR:-emacsclient}'` into my .pdbrc.py. The only tiny bit I miss is the transfer of focus from emacs to the independent console when appropriate (I've preferred non-emacs console).