# python debugging in emacs with gud-gdb type functionality

Tags: python, c, debugging, emacs

Is it possible to set up a python debugging environment in emacs to mimic that provided by gud-gdb when debugging C?

e.g. the ability to set a breakpoint with `pdb.set_trace()` and have a arrow annotation in the relevant source code file highlighting your progress as you step into/over statements and functions

I'm really missing this functionality when trying to debug python code after a bout of C debugging, all from within emacs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that functionality exists and should be working if you are in python mode.  Does emacs indicate that you have python mode active?

Note with emacs 24x and the regular `M-x shell` you may need to add a hook as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285046/how-do-i-enable-pdbtrack-python-debugging-in-emacs-24-x-shell).  It will work out of the box if you run with the `M-x python-shell-send*` commands.

I haven't tried pdb++ but that might be an alternative for you to try.  See the answer here: [Emacs: using pdbtrack (python.el)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758461/emacs-using-pdbtrack-python-el)

Comment: ahh i'm on 24.3.1 - have you fixed for this ver or did you revert back to 23?

Comment: I found it actually works if you run your python script using M-x python-shell-send-file but not when you run inside a regular M-x shell.  I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285046/how-do-i-enable-pdbtrack-python-debugging-in-emacs-24-x-shell) on it since I need to use M-x shell.