# How do I enable pdbtrack python debugging in emacs 24.x shell?

Tags: python, emacs, pdb

With emacs 23.x, pdbtrack integration (giving you the arrow pointing to the current line of code) works with the regular `M-x shell RET`.  This is useful, for example, to drop into the debugger while running automated tests with a Makefile.

**In emacs 24.x, this no longer works.**  I notice that if I run a python script with `M-x python-shell-send-file` then the pdbtrack integration works.  But it does not work when running python via a standard emacs shell (`M-x shell RET`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this snippet:

```
(require 'python)

(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  (add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'python-pdbtrack-comint-output-filter-function t))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
```

to prevent the pdbtrack stuff from trying to work on other buffers (eg gdb buffers).

Comment: I thought at first that this snippet had no effect but then realized maybe I'm supposed to change 'my-mode-hook to 'python-mode-hook.  True?  I'm new to using hooks.

Comment: Sorry! I blindly went through and changed things from my actual user name to "my", and did one too many. It is shell-mode-hook you want, not my-mode-hook nor python-mode-hook.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this problem by adding the following hook to your `.emacs` file:

```
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'python-pdbtrack-comint-output-filter-function)
```